# How to remove string node from json response

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I want to get this **JSON** response without string node in ***ASP.net webservice***.

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
[{"bookname":"Love Stories","name":"Vave Microtech","email":"anilkumar@vavemicrotechtt.com","mobile":"918010066285","address":"Sushant tower sec-56, Gurgaon (India)","nearestarea":"gurgaon"},]
</string>
```

Comment: How are you processing the results?

Answer (score 3):

Just change the method **return type to void** and write string with the **Response.Write()** method like this.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void TestMethod()
{
   // your actual Json  
   string srtJson="[{\"bookname\":\"Love Stories\"}]";

   HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
   HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(srtJson);


}
```

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";