# Remove xml tags from json

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

The web method returns the json string in this format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
[{"PKAdminUserId":1,"Username":"one","Password":"onep"},
{"PKAdminUserId":2,"Username":"two","Password":"twop"}]
</string>
```

Due to this reason, the data is not bound to the table. If I hardcode the data to `$scope.Users` without the `xml/string` tags, it works fine.
How to get only the json data from webmethod, without the `xml` or `<string>` tags.

**.aspx:**

```
<table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>Password</th>
                </tr>                
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr data-ng-repeat="User in Users track by $index">
                    <td>{{User.PKAdminUserId}}</td>
                    <td>{{User.Username}}</td>
                    <td>{{User.Password}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

**.asmx:**

```
[WebMethod]        
        public string GetUsers()
        {
            AdminUser obj;
            List<AdminUser> lstAdminUsers = new List<AdminUser>();
            obj = new AdminUser();
            obj.PKAdminUserId = 1;
            obj.Username = "one";
            obj.Password = "onep";
            lstAdminUsers.Add(obj);
            var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(lstAdminUsers);            
            return json;
}
```

**userCtrl.js:**

```
$scope.Users = [];
$scope.GetUsers = function () {
        var promise = Factory.GetUsers();
        promise.then(function (success) {
            console.log(success.data);
            $scope.Users = success.data;
        },
        function (error) {
            console.log("ERR : " + error);
        })
    }
```

**Solution:**

Found my solution from @Sain Pradeep's link. Here is how my Web method now looks like:

```
[WebMethod]
public void AddUsers()
{
AdminUser obj;
List<AdminUser> lstAdminUsers = new List<AdminUser>();
obj = new AdminUser();
obj.PKAdminUserId = 1;
obj.Username = "one";
obj.Password = "onep";
lstAdminUsers.Add(obj);
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Context.Response.Clear();
Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write((serializer.Serialize(
                      serializer.Serialize(lstAdminUsers))));
}
```

**output:**

```
[{"PKAdminUserId":1,"Username":"one","Password":"onep"}]
```

Comment: Please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/29667153/795683

Comment: I wonder why it had to be serialized twice to get the result. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4):

You should directly return the data as Json, and not as Xml (to avoid the wrapping).

Try to update your webmethod like this :

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]    
[WebMethod]        
public List<AdminUser> GetUsers()
{
    AdminUser obj;
    List<AdminUser> lstAdminUsers = new List<AdminUser>();
    obj = new AdminUser();
    obj.PKAdminUserId = 1;
    obj.Username = "one";
    obj.Password = "onep";
    lstAdminUsers.Add(obj);

    obj = new AdminUser();
    obj.PKAdminUserId = 2;
    obj.Username = "two";
    obj.Password = "twop";
    lstAdminUsers.Add(obj);

    return lstAdminUsers;
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but did not work. The result is now in XML format. Please see the updated question

Comment: hum... my solution works with web methods in pages. Maybe you can move to a WCF service? there are a lot more options to play with